# MobileFirst App Diagnostic

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can I disable the APP DIAGNOSTIC screenshot after the occurrence of an error ? It appears selecting it on an error POPUP in the app itself. This app is hybrid and based on MobileFirst 7.1.

[image: App diagnostic screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no flag to remove the 'Details' button that appears in the pop-up that leads to this Diagnostics table.

I believe you should be able to override the dialog all-together and provide your own by using the `onConnectionFailure` property in the **initOptions.js** file. You should have there the following snippet

```
// # The callback function to invoke in case application fails to connect to MobileFirst Server
//onConnectionFailure: function (){},
```